# suggested values

Tags: tfs

I had added  some suggested values to a field in a Work item, But now when i try to update the value, changes are not reflected.

If I delete the suggested values , then as expected  it is not suggesting anything.But when I reenter the same values again. It is going back to old value and changes are not reflected.

Basically , I added a suggested value with some letter in upper case while some in lower and I want to fix this problem after the workitem is uploaded to the server.

Is it Ok to go in SQL server and updated the table, If so then can someone which table hold the suggested values.

Answer (score 1):

In TFS2010, WitAdmin console application is used to Import\Export WorkItem Types, WitAdmin will be available in (Drive:\%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE).

To modify a Work Item Type in TFS, first you have to download the Work Item Type using below exportwitd command.

witadmin exportwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:project /n:typename [/f:filename] [/e:encoding] [/exportgloballists]

ex: witadmin exportwitd /collection:”http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection” /p:”Demo” /n:Bug/f:”c:\WorkItemTypes\Bug.xml”

Then you can perform the modification on the downloaded Work Item Type. You have to search the required field in xml file and under its suggested values you can add your new value and then save.

Now,you have to upload the xml to TFS Server using the Importwitd command.

witadmin importwitd /collection:collectionurl [/p:project] /f:filename [/e:encoding] [/v]

ex:
witadmin importwitd /collection:”http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection” /p:” Demo” /f:” c:\WorkItemTypes\Bug.xml”

Comment: Have tried this solution already but in vain. Even I tried clearing the cache folder in the app folder. 

But i noticed , that the field is marked as dimension. Does it has to do something with the problem.

Comment: Can you provide details about the Field to which you are trying to add suggested values? Is it a Default Field or a Custom Field which you have created. If possible paste the Field entry of of this WorkItem Type xml file.